# Pandas: How do I get back original indexing after groupby operations

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe in long format.
For the sake of this operation I have three columns:
Position, Timepoint, ID.
I want to know how many objects I have at each position over time, so I do.

```
temp=df.groupby(['Position', 'Timepoint'])['ID'].count()
temp=temp.to_frame()
```

I then Have a multiindex for each position such as ('A1', 1)
If I look at the output of temp.index the information of the different column names is still retained.
How do I split the index again back into the original columns?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Position', 'Timepoint'],sort=False)['ID'].count().reset_index()`?

Comment: I *think* you are looking for `GroupBy.transform`, so `...['ID'].transform('count')`. Othwerwise a count aggregation collapses your data to one row per group key, so it doesn't make sense to have any relationship to the original index.

Comment: I think you are right @ALollz

Comment: @ansez thanks, I did not know reset_index() would work like that with comma delimited indecs.